# Google Charts Timeline Labels display outside of box

Tags: javascript, svg, pygooglechart, google-visualization

I am using google timeline chart in my project. Below the screen shot attach.
Some label display out side of bar. Any Solution that text fit in bar. Reference link [Google timeline chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) .
 [image]